# Standard image gallery app

Tags: android, memory, optimization, bitmap, gallery

I'm trying to write simple application where I can swipe between photos (like that standard gallery app on each device). Standard one demonstrates impressive performance - it displays next photo instantly while takes only about 15 MB of memory. It seems like it keeps next and previous images in memory so it doesn't have delay due to loading them from sd-card. I think that if the application keeps at least 3 `Bitmap` objects of such size in memory, it will take much more than 15 MB. So how it works? Don't use `Bitmap` or what? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the bitmap on the screen might not be the size of your original file.

Take a 720p screen for example, a 4096*3072 picture will be decoded and re-sized to screen size.

Even the APP might be using ARGB8888 format to display a bitmap, the memory size is 1280*720*4 = 3686400 bytes, that is about 3.5M.

And if we use RGB565 format, the size will be half small then.

What's more, not all the picture is 'full screen'.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes it makes sense, but you can easily zoom image, so the app should keep the picture in original size, shouldn't it?

Comment: The image on the external storage is at its original size. But to decode an image to bmp format and keep it in the memory should not use the huge size. A 4096*3072 picture might take up to 50Mbyte! It's unreasonable on a mobile device.

Comment: Yes, but when an image is maximally zoomed I can move around it and it's very big, it seems like it really has 8Mpixels and the application takes only 15 MB of memory like before zooming. Is it some device low-level special trick which is not accessible for me?